# Eclipse doesn't add files to workspace when they are added through windows explorer

Tags: eclipse, codeigniter, file, project-management, visibility

I have recently added the reCaptcha library for CodeIgniter (by copying files from the extracted zip into the application folder). Although the files exist in windows explorer and in the open file dialogue in eclipse, they are not added to the eclipse project view; although the  project view's root directory *is* the application folder. Do you know why this happens, and what I can do about it?

Thanks,

Lemiant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refresh the Project. Select the project or folder you want to refresh and either right click it and click refresh from the window that pops up, or go to file -> refresh

Comment: Yea...eclipse can be fairly annoying like that, but most problems of this sort are solved by refreshing the project scope.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried refreshing/rebuilding your workspace? I've done that from time to time, even changing the workspace and changing back, and that solved it.

Answer (score 0):

In the preferences menu under General > Workspace there's an option "refresh automatically". Not sure if it does what you want though